# How to write a regedit value that would take information from a url and send it to cmd?

Tags: cmd, command-line, syntax, registry, regedit

my goal is to launch a .vnc file from html, i have now figured out how to open it directly via cmd.

```
C:\Program Files\TightVNC>start tvnviewer.exe -optionsfile=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Links\test.vnc
```

so this works, but now i need to figure out how to make a regedit so that i can make URL links for all the files saved on our intranet, ideally i would have just the file name as a variable in the URL and the rest be done by the regedit value, so that whenever a link in our html file is pressed, cmd is launched and executes the command and replacing the variable by the name of the file.

I imagine it like this customurl://testfile

and it should automatically launch my vnc application stated above, with the -optionsfile being at the same address as i specified, only the name would now be testfile.vnc.

edit: forgot to mention that i already do have a regedit entry for the custom url protocol and keys such as customurl>shell>open>command

Comment: The way to use `start`: `start "" tvnviewer.exe`

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand this correctly somebadhat

Comment: To find out how to use start read `start /?`